# Which set does this flywheel-like assembly belong to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Please help me identify the set this part belongs to.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This assembly consist of two parts. Well, technically, four parts, as there are two Technic 2L pins in Black, but these come in multiple sets so out of interest.

Top one in Orange is [Flywheel Fairing Lion Shape with Gold and Blue Feathers Pattern (70102)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=115354#T=C)

[image]

And the bottom one is [Flywheel Plate 2 x 8 with Metal Flywheel and Dark Azure Tire (Chima Rip Cord Base)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11125c01&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)

[image]

Top part was available only in [70102, CHI Waterfall](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70102-1) set. And the bottom one was included in [22 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=11125c01&colorID=85&in=A).

[image]

Comment: What an odd set, I thought it would be part of some exotic motorcycle but this is more obscure.

Comment: @Mast Arguably a drunken, anthropomorphic lion riding a rocket-powered ripcord unicycle with a golden-feathered lion fairing in a jungle is the most exotic motorcycle concept ever.